# What is the best way to add HTML block with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML document which I want to modify on the client side (with Javascript or jQuery).

Now I do it in the following way:

```
$('div.my-block').html('');     // erasing the block contents
$.each(users,function(i,val){   // `users` variable is am array with all data I need to insert as HTML
  $('div.my-block').html('\     // Here and after is a big block of HTML
    <li>\
      <p>'+val.name+'</p>\
    </li>\
  ');
});
```

This works fine, but there are some drawbacks:

1. This code don't looks fancy in Notepad++ as HTML block represented as a simple string literal
2. I have to put back-slashes and variables manually and I could make mistakes for big HTML pieces.

One thing comes to my mind: I could put HTML snippet in the container I'm erasing in the beginning, multiply one as many times as I need. During this copy and paste process I could replace placeholders with variable values.

In this case I could have a good looking HTML with all syntax highlighting, I could avoid putting HTML in the JS file (which is a bad practice I suppose).

Is there any comments or other ideas?

Comment: What is the fanciest way? With your pinky out, of course!

Comment: use a template engine and html5 `<template>` tags.

Comment: There are also ES2015 (aka "ES6") [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: To down-voters: could you please comment what is bad with my question?

Comment: Probably the fact that you keep using the word "fancy", which makes your question sound frivolous and hard to take seriously.

Comment: @JohnConde, could you please make you idea more clear? English is a foreign language for me...

Comment: @BoltClock, I'm sorry for that. As I said above I'm not so good in English so I used this word as a substitute for 'best', 'beautiful'. Is this word ('fancy') really so bad?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave notepad++ and start to use sublime text - https://www.sublimetext.com/

With some plugins, your HTML code inserted in JS will be easier to read.
But to be honest I don't think there are better - more clear ways to do it.

Comment: Regarding Sublime text: I actually really love how it looks. But when I tried to move from NP++ I didn't find how to edit files directly on the server (NP++ can do it with FTP plugin)

Comment: You have a lot of plugins for sublime - Did you check this one ?https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Simple%20FTP%20Deploy

Comment: I think... You can use ajax to import external file with HTML in Javascript. By this way, you can write HTML in "nice and clear" way and just import it to JS file. For example: //// .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )